# Express, NodeJs, Postgres, and Multer - Multiple fields upload - undefined Postman

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, multer, multiple-file-upload

I'm working on a rest API's PUT route, that updates fields in my postgres database with images or at least the image path to be stored there. While testing using postman, the fields keep returning undefined in my request body in postman's console. Is there a obvious reason that I don't see why files are not being received or picked up on by multer when selected for upload?

```
    //DB Table 
    
    async function updateChannel({channelname, profile_avatar, slider_pic1, slider_pic2, slider_pic3}) {
     
      try {
        const userprofile = getUserChannelByChannelName(channelname);
         await client.query(
          `
                  UPDATE users_channel
                  SET profile_avatar=$2, slider_pic1=$3, slider_pic2=$4, slider_pic3=$5
                  WHERE channelname=$1
                  RETURNING *;
                `,
               [channelname, profile_avatar, slider_pic1, slider_pic2, slider_pic3]
        );
        return userprofile;
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
     
    }
    
    
    //Multer Setup

const path = require("path");

const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./useruploads");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "_" + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });



    
    
    //API PUT ROUTE
    
    usersRouter.put(
      "/myprofile/update/:channelname",
      upload.fields([
      { name: "avatar", maxCount: 1 },
      { name: "slide1", maxCount: 1 },
      { name: "slide2", maxCount: 1 },
      { name: "slide3", maxCount: 1 },
    ]),
      requireUser,
      async (req, res, next) => {
        const { channelname } = req.params;
        const { profile_avatar, slider_pic1, slider_pic2, slider_pic3 } = req.body;
        try {
          const updateData = {
            profile_avatar: req.files.avatar,
            slider_pic1: req.files.slide1,
            slider_pic2: req.files.slide2,
            slider_pic3: req.files.slide3,
          };
          console.log(updateData);
          const channel = await getUserChannelByChannelName(channelname);
          const updatedchannel = await updateChannel(channelname, updateData);
          res.send({channel, updatedchannel});
    
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Could not update user profile", error);
          next(error);
        }
      }
    );
```